# sympyで、分配して約分する方法を教えてください

Tags: python3, sympy

Jを変数として、以下を変形したいです。ゴールは、分数式ではなく正式になることです。2*(J + 18)+ 2とかになれば成功です。宜しくお願いします。

```
(2 + 2/(J + 18))*(J + 18)
```

追記
すみません、本当は行列の成分で分配を行いたいのです。コードは以下です。最終的には、行列の成分を正式だけにしたいのです。

```
B=sp.Matrix([[0],[0],[-e*(M*r*H/(z*(M*H**2+J)))],[e/z]])
    
P=sp.Matrix.eye(4)   
R = sp.Matrix([[3]])
K= sp.Matrix([[5,3,2,1]])
        
inv_R=R.inv()
tB=B.transpose()
    
 print(K-inv_R@tB@P)
 print("\n")
 print((K-inv_R@tB@P)*((J + 18))
```

参考までに、数値はこう定義します。

```
M=2 
r=1 
H=3 
J=sp.symbols("J") 

z=1 
e=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ダミー変数(`_o`)を用意して、`J+18` と入れ替えてから `simplify` します。元に戻す際には [sympy.core.expr.UnevaluatedExpr()](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=unevaluatedexpr#sympy.core.expr.UnevaluatedExpr) を使って `J+18` が評価されない様にしています。

```py
x, _o = sp.symbols("x o") 
x = J + 18
print(
  ((K-inv_R@tB@P)*x)
  .applyfunc(
    lambda f: f.subs(x, _o).simplify().subs(_o, sp.UnevaluatedExpr(x))))

=>
Matrix([[5*J + 90, 3*J + 54, 2 + 2*(J + 18), 0.666666666666667*J + 12.0]])
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。必ずしもJ+18の形のまま残したいというわけではなく分母に変数を持つ項が消えてくれればそれで良いのですが、それだとどういうコードになりますでしょうか？

Comment: その場合は `sp.simplify((K-inv_R@tB@P)*(J+18))` でよろしいかと。